# Is it not possible to autoplay embedded YouTube videos using UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm having an issue trying to autoplay my UIWebView.

Yes, I know there are tons of questions regarding it already.

Fist off, here's my simple code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let youtubePlayer:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))

    youtubePlayer.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/EzNinU0g-Q0")!) )

    self.view.addSubview(youtubePlayer)
}
```

Now here's what I found:

1. [How to autoplay a YouTube video in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717754/how-to-autoplay-a-youtube-video-in-a-uiwebview)
2. [Youtube video autoplay inside UIWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385791/youtube-video-autoplay-inside-uiwebview)
3. [How to get YouTube autoplay to work in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350247/how-to-get-youtube-autoplay-to-work-in-uiwebview)

I did as suggested with the following codes:

```
youtubePlayer.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
youtubePlayer.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```

That did nothing.

4. [autoplay on video in UIWebview,iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429042/autoplay-on-video-in-uiwebview-ios)

This solution works, however, it's not for embedded videos, which is what I'm using.

Therefore, is there no way to auto-play using the UIWebView?

Those questions were posted years ago, so I'm not sure how things have changed.

Can anyone suggest an alternative? Since I have a `UITableView` set up to where, when the user selects a cell (video), it will show the UIWebView of the video.

However, I would like, if possible for the video to start playing immediately when the user selects a video instead of having to press play again to play it.

I have a similar layout design to apps like TubiMusic and Tubex, but those apps are able to autoplay videos while I can't figure out how to do the same.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Swift-ified version of the top-rated obj-c answer to [How to autoplay a YouTube video in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717754/how-to-autoplay-a-youtube-video-in-a-uiwebview).

> Apparently the problem was with the nil base url, when I changed it to resourceURL the autoplay worked.

Here's the code:

```
var youTubeVideoHTML: String = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\"; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'%0.0f', height:'%0.0f', videoId:'%@', events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady, } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>"

func playVideoWithId(videoId: String) {
var html: String = String(format: youTubeVideoHTML, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height, videoId)

}
```

Comment: YES!!!...thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Pangu glad it helped you!

Comment: I tested this but the video is not autoplayed. Can you help me please?

Comment: @Pangu can you help Llg with auto-playing youtube videos?—seems like my answer didn't help them. See the comment above this.

Comment: @owlswipe `webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: Bundle.main.resourceURL)`

By doing this it only buffers doesn't play.

Comment: I found it working like this


 `webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: Bundle.main.resourceURL)`

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale Cool! Looks like that's working for me too.

Comment: @owlswipe Great, If you dont mind can you have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117038/access-data-of-notification-swift-3)

Answer (score 2):

Autoplay parameter does not work on web view. Instead you have to use the JS apis to determine the readiness state of the player and then send a play command to that.

You can use this pod 
https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player

or you can use the google provided code

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: Thanks!...This also worked